# Download YouTube CMS Reports using gsutil?

Tags: youtube, gsutil

I am wondering if there is a way for us to access the CMS reports via the gsutil?

I've tried guessing links, but I either get access denied or bucket doesn't exist. Also tried searching but most results are just video tutorials on YT for installing gsutil.

Any info/links would be greatly appreciated!